# Adding items in a model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm working on a project where I've to add the first and second semester scores together. I summed up the first semester results in my models and also for the second semester also. But I've difficult summing the two models i.e the first and second. Here's my code for better understanding.

```
class First(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    midscore = models.FloatField()
    finalscore = models.FloatField()

    def__str__(self):
        return self.user

    def get_total_first_score(self):
        return self.midscore + self.finalscore


class Second(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    midscore = models.FloatField()
    finalscore = models.FloatField()

    def__str__(self):
        return self.user

    def get_total_second_score(self):
        return self.midscore + self.finalscore
```

Now, how can I add the `ger_total_score` for the two semester. I tried something like this, but it's not giving me any results, since it's not under any model.

```
def get_total_scores:
    get_total_first_score + get_total_second_score
```

Comment: Why you don't combine it fields into one model?

Comment: @binpy can you please show me an example, because as you can see, I'm using two different models

Comment: please check my answer below, option 3.

Comment: @binpy, thanks for your time. You examples were worth the time, but I've been thinking how to Integrate the method, i.e d third option in my HTML, since the def get_total_score, is a def on it's own

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to combine they fields into one model for better use. For example:

### Option 1

```
class Score(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('first_score', 'First Score'),
        ('second_score', 'Second Score')
    )
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='first_score', 
                              choices=STATUS_CHOICES)

    midscore = models.FloatField()
    finalscore = models.FloatField()

    @property
    def total_scores(self):
        return self.midscore + self.finalscore

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.user
```

And in ORM, you can create dual object of `Score` with different `status`, for example:

```
>>> first_score = Score.objects.create(user=user, status='first_score',
                                       midscore=95.2, finalscore=83.0)
>>>
>>>
>>> second_score = Score.objects.create(user=user, status='second_score',
                                        midscore=72.1, finalscore=78.5)
>>>
>>> total_scores = first_score.total_scores + second_score.total_scores
328.79999999999995
```

### Option 2

Store all fields into one model. For example:

```
class Score(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='first_score', 
                              choices=STATUS_CHOICES)

    first_midscore = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    first_finalscore = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)

    second_midscore = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    second_finalscore = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)

    @property
    def first_total_scores(self):
        midscore = self.first_midscore or 0
        finalscore = self.first_finalscore or 0
        return midscore + finalscore

    @property
    def second_total_scores(self):
        midscore = self.second_midscore or 0
        finalscore = self.second_finalscore or 0
        return midscore + finalscore

    @property
    def total_scores(self):
        return self.first_total_scores + self.second_total_scores

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.user
```

So, in your ORM you just need to create one object of `Score`.

```
>>> # step 1, create the `first` scores.
>>> Score.objects.create(
  user=user,
  first_midscore=95.2,
  first_finalscore=83.0
)
>>>
>>> # step 2, use created object
>>> Score.objects.get_or_create(
  user=user, 
  second_midscore=72.1,
  second_finalscore=78.5
)
>>>
>>> # step 3, get the total of both scores.
>>> score = Score.objects.get(user=user)
>>> score.first_total_scores
178.2
>>> score.second_total_scores
150.6
>>> score.total_scores
328.79999999999995
```

### Option 3

But, If you realy want to use as your own method, you can use this;

```
def get_total_scores(first_object, second_object):
    first_score = first_object.get_total_first_score()
    second_score = second_object.get_total_second_score()
    return first_score + second_score
```

In your ORM;

```
>>> first = First.objects.create(user=user, midscore=95.2, finalscore=83.0)
>>>
>>> second = Second.objects.create(user=user, midscore=72.1, finalscore=78.5)
>>>
>>> get_total_scores(first, second)
328.79999999999995
```

But, I think that case just same with;

```
>>> first.get_total_first_score() + second.get_total_second_score()
328.79999999999995
```